# Why can't `main` return a double or String rather than int or void?

Tags: programming-languages, history

In many languages such as C, C++, and Java, the `main` method/function has a return type of `void` or `int`, but not `double` or `String`.   What might be the reasons behind that?

I know a little bit that we can't do that because `main` is called by runtime library and it expects some syntax  like `int main()` or `int main(int,char**)` so we have to stick to that.

So my question is:  why does `main` have the type signature that it has, and not a different one?

Comment: What would a double return value *mean*? What would a string return value *mean*?

Comment: k i understand that it doesn't mean anything.But any other reasons and conventions?

Comment: i think it doesn't mean anything,simply because universally it was choosen that 0 for normal exit and a non zero for a abnormal.An int was chosen as the simplest data type with broad cross language compatibility.@delnan

Comment: @sunny From what I've been able to gather from my experience with Unix-like OSs, 0 is used as a "normal exit" (0 errors) because it's unambiguous when compared to other integer values. Since most (not all) modern languages are designed to be be similar to (if not designed on the back of) C, and since C was used to write Unix, I'd say it was a historical decision by KnR.

Comment: @sunny "broad cross language compatibility" was not an issue. C and UNIX were written in tandem. The reason many other languages return ints is because they were designed to work in UNIX or UNIX-like environments.

Comment: @GrahamLee i don't know much about UNIX.So will you say why int return type is necessary for the UNIX or UNIX like environments.

Comment: @sunny the standard defines two exit conditions, EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE (later revisions added sysexits.h which define other reasons for failing, not relevant for now). That means you _have_ to pass something to the calling environment, though of course that _could_ be done by syscall (e.g. exit()) rather than return value. Why specifically they decided main() should return this information, you would need to take up with the designers.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The return value of `main` is to be passed to the operating system (*any* operating system) in a single, consistent way.  The information that the operating system needs to know is "did the program terminate successfully, or was there an error?"

If this is a string, the response becomes difficult in different languages.  The internals of a Pascal string (first byte is length) and a FORTRAN string (fixed, padded to some value) and a C string (null terminated) are all different.  This would make returning a consistent value to the operating system challenging.  Assuming that this was solved, what would you do to answer the question the OS had of the program?  String comparisons are fraught with errors ("success" vs "Success"), and while the error may be more useful to a human, it is more difficult for the operating system or another program (shell) to deal with.  There also were significant differences even in the strings themselves -- [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) (with all of its code pages) vs. ASCII.

Floats and doubles provide no additional value over the integer for communicating back data to the OS (and shell).  For the most part, neither of these parts of the computer deal with floating point numbers.  Doubles are also not enumerable making comparisons difficult.  Not being enumerable, they make reporting what the error was (assuming you have picked a particular value for success).  Again, floating points are not consistent - a float on an 8 bit machine was different than the float on a 16 bit and a 32 bit machine (and those are just the 'normal' ones - even within IBM, floating point wasn't standardized between machines by the same manufacturer until the 1980's).  And then you've got decimal vs. binary computers.  Floating point values aren't consistent and don't provide meaningful data back.

That really leaves us with the byte and integer as options.  The convention that was established was '0' was success, and anything else was an error.  An integer gives more room than a byte for reporting the error.  It can be enumerated (return of 1 means XYZ, return of 2 means ABC, return of 3, means DEF, etc..) or used as flags (`0x0001` means this failed, `0x0002` means that failed, `0x0003` means both this and that failed).  Limiting this to just a byte could easily run out of flags (only 8), so the decision was probably to use an integer.

Comment: I think main is called by c/c++ runtime library before os call it which is also a piece of code loaded along with our code and called by the os@MichaelT

Comment: `main()` is invoked different ways on different operating systems.  [In C, how is the main() method initially called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469955/in-c-how-is-the-main-method-initially-called) goes into this.

Comment: I think that the key point to understand is that `main` - unlike other functions in any program - is not part of a protocol defined by the programmer, but the protocol used to interface with the host (OS). You don't get to pick it because it was never yours to pick. At a more pragmatic level, UNIX expects an int to be returned by a process, and so the C-to-UNIX protocol does exactly that. An analogous argument can be made for argument-passing: if C had been invented for an OS/host that passed only numbers as arguments (e.g. no command-line), the arguments would be ints instead of strings.

Comment: IBM took the concept of code pages from EBCDIC to their PCs. They still haunt us today, going on 35 years after the introduction of the IBM 5150. 7-bit *ASCII* is codepage-less, but 8-bit character codes can be interpreted in many different ways even on a single computer, depending on settings -- let alone the codepages that code for multi-byte encodings. So it's actually even *worse* than what you allude to in the last sentence of the second paragraph.

Comment: @EuroMicelli that's a very nice information actually thanks for that :)

Comment: In Plan 9, processes actually return strings as exit codes.

Comment: @FUZxxl from [The Structure of a Multi Service Operating System](http://people.inf.ethz.ch/troscoe/pubs/UCAM-CL-TR-376.pdf) - "Instead, communication has to rely on conventions, which are prone to error and do not scale." - the essence of which I mentioned.  Plan 9 also was significantly after some crucial standardizations. At the time that C (and B, and BCPL, and Algol, and...) was written, this was not standardized at all and not a viable option. This is further explored in [Keith's answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/203117/40980).

Answer (score 28):

Well, it *could*.

For example, in the dialect of C used in the [Plan 9](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/plan9/) operating system `main` is normally declared as a `void` function, but the exit status is returned to the calling environment by passing a string pointer to the `exits()` function. The empty string denotes success, and any non-empty string denotes some kind of failure. This *could* have been implemented by having `main` return a `char*` result.

And it would certainly be possible to implement a system with a `float` or `double` exit status.

So why `int`? It's just a matter of convention -- and there's a *tremendous* value in having operating systems and programs that run under them obey a common convention.

The Unix convention is to use an integer status code, with 0 denoting success and non-zero denoting failure (because typically there's only one way to succeed, but multiple ways to fail). I don't know whether that convention originated with Unix; I suspect it came from earlier operating systems.

Floating-point would be a more difficult convention, because (a) floating-point support is not universal, (b) it's more difficult to define a mapping between floating-point values and error conditions, (c) different systems use different floating-point representations, and (d) just imagine the fun of tracking down a rounding error in your program's exit status. Integers, on the other hand, lend themselves very well to enumerating error codes.

Plan 9, as I mentioned, uses strings, but that imposes some complexity for memory management, character encoding, etc. It was, as far as I know, a new idea when Plan 9 implemented it, and it didn't replace the existing widespread convention.

(Incidentally, in C++ `main` can *only* return `int`, and in C `void main` is permitted only if the compiler specifically supports it. Many compilers don't complain very loudly if you write `void main`, but it's only a slight exaggeration to say that it's *wrong*.)

Answer (score 9):

The value returned by the main method is an "exit code". It's used by the caller application (normally bash) to test if the program ended as expected. Returning an integer is the easiest way to do it on the OS level. Double makes no sense for error code and a String is hard to maintain in OS level (there is no GC).

Comment: Why does a string need to be garbage collected while a integer does not?

Comment: @Brad, strings have variable length to them and would be in essence the same as passing back an array which could be one character or it could be thousands.  Dynamic memory would be a pain while an int is a rather fixed size that isn't so hard to handle.

Answer (score -4):

main should return the status of the program which is executed.wether it is executed successfully(return 0 that is EXIT_SUCCESS) or not(return 1 means EXIT_FAILURE)
any non zero number conveys the same meaning but zero indicates no errors or successful execution..

Comment: this doesn't seem to offer anything substantial over points made (and much better explained) in prior answers that were posted several years ago